# Critique my prototypal inheritance pattern

Tags: javascript, oop, prototypal-inheritance

I've decided to use Object.create, as it seems much more intuitive than using 'new' and having to write Car.prototype.func1 = function(){} for each function, for example; seems a bit too DRY.

I had an epiphany of using $.extend to augment properties and functions, making it easier to grab code from any object I wanted to use. Once the object's extended, I then use Object.create() to set the prototype, so the functions are common to all instances and pass in the properties as the second parameter.

Is the following pattern okay? [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x8m3pt0f/)

```
// props use Object.defineProperties() format; can configure each prop as writable, enumerable, etc

var Vehicle = {
    props : { 'colour' : {value:'black'}, 'wheels' : {value:4} },
    proto : { 'drive' : function(){console.log('drive ' + this.colour + ' ' +     this.wheels);} }
};

var Ferrari = {
    props : { 'colour' : {value:'red'}, 'seats' : {value:2} },
    proto : { 'fast' : function(){console.log('ferrari power ' + this.colour + ' ' + this.wheels + ' ' + this.seats);} }
}; 

function init(){

    // copy Vehicle object, so it remains untouched
    var vehicle = $.extend(true,{}, Vehicle); 

    // augment vehicle super-class with sub-class
    $.extend(vehicle.props, Ferrari.props);
    $.extend(vehicle.proto, Ferrari.proto);

    // prototypal inheritance
    var ferrari = Object.create(vehicle.proto, vehicle.props);
    ferrari.drive();
    ferrari.fast();
}

init();
```

Edit : I've abandoned this idea, too messy; I'm using a prototypal pattern, shown at the end of [this article](http://davidshariff.com/blog/javascript-inheritance-patterns/).

Comment: any plan to use ES6 class?

Comment: @BryanChen - No, it's just syntactic sugar.

Comment: But it solve the problem you had for `Car.prototype.func1 = function(){}` (seems a bit too DRY). Syntactic sugar is _not_ a reason to not using a feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use `$.extend` for inheritance, and you should declare the inheritance right away at the definition of your class, not somewhen later in an `init` function.
Also your "*augment vehicle super-class with sub-class*" seems really backwards. This is emphasized by the need to "*copy Vehicle object, so it remains untouched*" and that you are creating your `ferrari` instance from `vehicle`, not from `Ferrari`.

I'd recommend to use two helper functions:

```
function inherit(superClass, props, proto) {
    return {
        props: $.extend(Object.create(superClass.props), props),
        proto: $.extend(Object.create(superClass.proto), proto)
    };
}
function create(template) {
    return Object.create(template.proto, template.props);
}
```

Which you could use like

```
var Vehicle = {
    props : { 'colour' : {value:'black'}, 'wheels' : {value:4} },
    proto : { 'drive' : function(){console.log('drive ' + this.colour + ' ' +     this.wheels);} }
};

var Ferrari = inherit(Vehicle, {
    'colour' : {value:'red'},
    'seats' : {value:2}
}, {
    'fast' : function(){console.log('ferrari power ' + this.colour + ' ' + this.wheels + ' ' + this.seats);}
});

var ferrari = create(Ferrari);
ferrari.drive();
ferrari.fast();
```

Apart from these problems, your pattern is quite fine. Using pure prototype inheritance is an established pattern. You may amend it by adding an initialisation function to your template objects (classes), named e.g. `.constructor`, and you're back at the power of the typical class pattern.

Comment: Thanks for your concise answer, much appreciated. I'm interested why you say you should not use $.extend for inheritance? Surely it seems like a perfect candidate for object augmentation, which is the very essence of JS.

Comment: @Data: Yes, if you want to augment objects then use `$.extend`. However, for (prototypal) *inheritance* you need `Object.create`. If you don't use that, changes to your prototype object will not be reflected on the instances that inherit their properties from it.

Answer (score 2):

It's creative code, but it feels obfuscated and introduces too much incidental complexity, such as the need for jQuery (which isn't necessarily a bad thing if your project already depends on jQuery). JavaScript specifically is designed based on prototypal inheritance... why not take advantage of it?

Also, regarding your feeling about adding prototype properties seeming too repetitive:

```
var Cat = function() { ... };

// then when defining the prototype...

Cat.prototype.purr = function() { ... };
Cat.prototype.meow = function() { ... };
```

You'll find that people usually recommend the above approach of defining prototype properties for several reasons (versus the approach I'm about to show below) because, for one, regarding garbage collection and elimination of circular references. However, if you're worried about "repeating yourself" too much, just set the prototype as a plain object:

```
Cat.prototype = {
  purr: purr,
  meow: meow
};

function purr() {
  // whatever
}

function meow() {
  // whatever
}
```

The second way of doing it, as shown above, takes advantage of JavaScript's function hoisting and introduces a concept similar to [the revealing module pattern](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#revealingmodulepatternjavascript).

Comment: Thanks for your answer; I've marked Bergi's answer as he ran with my idea.