# Critique my prototypal inheritance pattern - ver2

Tags: javascript, oop, prototypal-inheritance

A follow-up to my [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32002843/1837472) - my goal is to avoid the constructor function and create a pattern where I can **easily inherit functionality**.

The following code inherits as many objects as you want. The construct() function, uses Object.create() to place all the inherited objects onto the prototype and then instantiates the object with properties passed in; optionally, you can pass in other functions that are invoked on the objects context.

As a matter of house-keeping, the init function removes itself, so you end up with a clean object, i.e. obj.props and then all the inherited functions/props residing on the first prototype chain. Ordinarily, when cascading chained inheritance, you end up with a multi-level _proto__ chain, but here they all sit in the first link, so there's some look-up speed advantage by the compiler.

Again, I welcome your feedback...

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u9ax5xzz/)

```
var Vehicle = {
    colour : 'blue',
    info   : function() { console.log('wheels:' + this.wheels + ' colour:' + this.colour); }
};

var Car = {
    wheels : 4,
    drift  : function() { console.log('drifting'); }
};

var Bike = {
    wheels : 2,
    wheelie : function() { console.log('stunt riding'); }
};

var ferrari = construct( $.extend({}, Vehicle, Car),  {colour:'red'} ); 
var yamaha  = construct( $.extend({}, Vehicle, Bike) ); 

ferrari.drift(); // difting
ferrari.info(); // wheels:4 colour:red
yamaha.wheelie(); // stunt riding
yamaha.info(); // wheels:2 colour:blue

/*
    construct(proto, props, funcs)
    sets prototype functions from inherited classes
    invokes any functions passed
*/

function construct(proto, props, funcs)
{
    return Object.create(proto, {

        init : { value : function() {

            $.extend(this, props);
            if (funcs) for (var i=0; i<funcs.length; i++) funcs[i].call(this);
            delete this.init;

            return this;

        }, configurable : true } // used to delete init prop from object

    }).init(); 
}
```

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If this code works as intended, all this question is missing to be a good fit on [codereview.se], is a title that roughly says what the code does.

Comment: No I wont critique your code.  But I will critique your question: its offtopic.

Comment: The inheritance won't be live, and you will have copies of the properties everywhere. Don't reinvent the wheel, better use the typical inheritance pattern.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question should be on [*codereview.stackexchange.com*](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Where is `$.extend` defined?

Comment: @RobG I guess http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/

Comment: @Oriol—maybe, but jQuery isn't the only library to use *$*, nor to have an extend function. It's not tagged or mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inheritance won't be live, and you will have multiple copies of the properties.

Instead, I recommend normal inheritance with `Object.create`:

```js
var vehicle = {
  colour: 'blue',
  info: function() {
    console.log('wheels:' + this.wheels + ' colour:' + this.colour);
  }
};
var car = Object.assign(Object.create(vehicle), {
    wheels: 4,
    drift: function() { console.log('drifting'); }
});
var bike = Object.assign(Object.create(vehicle), {
    wheels: 2,
    wheelie: function() { console.log('stunt riding'); }
});
var ferrari = Object.assign(Object.create(car), {colour:'red'} ); 
var yamaha  = Object.create(bike);
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say "the inheritance won't be live?"

Comment: @grammar By live I mean that If you add some property to `vehicle`, it will be inherited by `ferrari`, even if it has already been created.

Comment: @Oriol - Object.assign is exactly the tool I've been looking for, thank you for bringing it to my attention.

Comment: @Oriol - What's the correct way to include an engine? https://jsfiddle.net/u9ax5xzz/3/ thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: @Data Objects can only inherit from another object, not multiple objects. So you should access it using `ferrari.engine.rev` instead of `ferrari.rev`. However, inheriting objects which have data (not only methods) is problematic, because all instances will inherit the same object, and thus changing that data on one instance will change it for all. So in this case I suggest assigning a copy of the object to each instance: `ferrari = Object.assign(Object.create(car), {engine: Object.create(engine)}`.

Comment: @Oriol - How do I fix the following fiddle? https://jsfiddle.net/u9ax5xzz/4/ (see output at bottom). If I have an object property in engine, then the porsche sees any changes ferrari makes (obj is by ref), but if I use a single prop, it's okay (prop is by val).

Comment: @Data Yes, this is a common problem when you want instances to inherit objects. You must clone the objects for each instance: https://jsfiddle.net/u9ax5xzz/6/. Note it would be cleaner to move that cloning code to a constructor.

Comment: @Oriol - I like Object.assign(), but I feel it clutters code. What about this version with a construct function? https://jsfiddle.net/u9ax5xzz/7/